# Unable to feed decoder output to encoder input using MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, video, encoding, android-mediacodec

I want to decode an mp4 file and feed the decoded output to an encoder and save it as a new mp4 file. This may sound something unwanted/weird. Also this can be done using the encoder input surface as decoder output surface. But I want to do some modification to this for achieving something different (by altering the order of the frames) once I get this working (using ByteBuffer).

But when I try this I get the below error when `Encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIME_OUT_US)`is invoked.

```
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:4886 CHECK_EQ( mCodec->mOMX->emptyBuffer( mCodec->mNode, bufferID, 0, buffer->size(), flags, timeUs),(status_t)OK) failed: -2147483648 vs. 0
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31543 (CodecLooper)
```

**Preparing Encoder**

```
// parameters for the encoder
private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
private static final int FRAME_RATE = 15;               // 15fps
private static final int IFRAME_INTERVAL = 10; 
private int mBitRate = 2000000;

private void prepareEncoder() throws IOException {

    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

    // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
    // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, mBitRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);
    Log.d(TAG, "format: " + format);

    mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

//        mEncoderInputSurface = mEncoder.createInputSurface();

    mEncoder.start();

    Log.d(TAG, "prepareEncoder: Done");

}
```

**Handling Decoder output**

It basically copies the output buffer data to an ArrayList which works as a queue for later use by encoder

```
private boolean doDecoderOutput(MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {

    int decoderStatus = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIME_OUT_US);

    if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
        //Output buffer not available will try later
        return false;
    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
        //Output buffer has changed
        //TODO this is deprecated
        mDecoderOutputBuffers = mDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
        return false;
    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
        //TODO what?
        return false;
    } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
        //Unknown status
    } else {
        //decoderStatus > 0

        boolean endOfStream = (bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0;

        ByteBuffer decoderOutputBuffer = mDecoderOutputBuffers[decoderStatus];

        if (!endOfStream) {
            if((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) == 0) {
                /*decoderOutputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                decoderOutputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);*/
                mEncoderInputQueue.add(new VideoChunk(decoderOutputBuffer, bufferInfo.flags, bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs));
                Log.d(TAG, "doDecoderOutput: " + "no config");
            }else{
                Log.d("ReverseTask", "doDecoderOutput : found config");
            }
        } else {
            mEncoderInputQueue.add(null);//This informs encoder that EOS has reached
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "doDecoderOutput: " + mDecoderOutputCount);
        mDecoderOutputCount++;

        mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, true);

        if (endOfStream) {
            //End of output stream
            Log.d(TAG, "doDecoderOutput: End of stream. Frame no :" + mDecoderOutputCount);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Handling Encoder Input**

```
private boolean doEncoderInput() {
    if (mEncoderInputQueue.isEmpty()) {
        //No frames queued for encode
        return false;
    }
    int inputBufferIndex = mEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIME_OUT_US);

    if (inputBufferIndex < 0) {
        //Input buffer not available. Try again later.
        return false;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderInput: " + mEncoderInputCount);
    mEncoderInputCount++;

    ByteBuffer encoderInputBuffer = mEncoderInputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];

    VideoChunk videoChunk = mEncoderInputQueue.remove(0);
    if (videoChunk == null) {
        //End of stream
        Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderInput: End of stream. Frame no " + mEncoderInputCount);
        mEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0L, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
    } else {

        Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderInput: chunk length : " + videoChunk.getLength() + " buffer capacity : " + encoderInputBuffer.capacity());
        videoChunk.copyTo(encoderInputBuffer);

        mEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, videoChunk.getLength(), videoChunk.getPresentationTimeUs(), 0);//videoChunk.getFlags());
        videoChunk.release();
        Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderInput: sent encoder input");
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Handling Encoder output.**

Eventually I should use a Muxer to save the stream to a file. Here I'm just ignoring the encoder output until I get this bunch of code error free.

```
private boolean doEncoderOutput(MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {

    Log.d("ReverseTask", "doEncoderOutput : start");
    int encoderStatus = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIME_OUT_US);

    Log.d("ReverseTask", "doEncoderOutput : encoder status " + encoderStatus);
    if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
        //Output buffer not available will try later
        return false;
    } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
        //Output buffer has changed
        //TODO this is deprecated
        mEncoderOutputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
        return false;
    } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
        //TODO what?
        return false;
    } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
        //Unknown status
    } else {
        //encoderStatus > 0

        Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderOutput: " + mEncoderOutputCount);
        mEncoderOutputCount++;

        ByteBuffer encoderOutputBuffer = mEncoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];


        Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderOutput: releasing output buffer");
        mEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

        if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            //End of output stream
            Log.d(TAG, "doEncoderOutput: End of stream. Frame no :" + mEncoderOutputCount);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have been learning to use the MediaCodec APIs for the last 1-2 weeks. Have reached this far from nowhere. But really stuck here. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)
```

It is common to get this error if you are passing uninitialized `BufferInfo` to `dequeueOutputBuffer(...)`. So, please, make sure you've called `bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo()` before it was used.